# Uncaught TypeError: a(...).countdown is not a function

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I have problem with popup counter. It wont display because I still get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: a(...).countdown is not a function

It refers to:

```
a("#counter").countdown({
    until: " + " + c.timeout + "s",
    format: "S",
    compact: true,    
    description: "",
    onExpiry: fbLikeDump
});
```

My whole js: [jsfiddles.net](http://jsfiddle.net/m3obmL02/2/)

Comment: Did you add the `countdown.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was jQuery libraries conflict.

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely an issue of:

1. Not adding `countdown.js`.
2. Adding `countdown.js` before jQuery loads.

Comment: I tried to but problem still exist. I added my whole js above.

Comment: Try to create a fiddle!

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/JakubSkowronski/m3obmL02/1/

But I had to load js as an external file.

Comment: This is the name of the function in popup.js

Its not my plugin I just trying to make it work.

Comment: I tried this method already. Now I get error:

`Uncaught Error: Couldn't cast [object Object] to a date object.`

The counter still are not visible after "Wait seconds", It should work like this: http://goo.gl/XiUj4s

Answer (score 0):

as they said you have to include these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

you might use `countdown.js` before `plugin.js`